# Help me with Goldschmidt Division Algorithm please

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to implement a program that performs division by using Goldschmidt Algorithm. But first, I need to understand the mathematical explanation of this algorithm and I am stuck in a little detail of this algorithm.

https://lauri.xn--vsandi-pxa.com/hdl/arithmetic/goldschmidt-division-algorithm.html

In this link
\begin{equation*}
D_{-1} = 7_{10} = 00000111.000000000000_{2}
\end{equation*}
and "*Initial reciprocal is the inverse of divisor which is calculated by shifting bits around the fraction point:*"
\begin{equation*}
F_{-1} = \frac{1}{D_{-1}} \approx 0.0546875_{10} = 00000000.000011100000_{2}
\end{equation*}

I have one doubt about how to find $F_{-1}$ here.

If $F_{-1} = \frac{1}{D_{-1}}$, then $F_{-1} = \frac{1}{7} = 0.142$

Please help me to understand how to find $F_{-1}$ for any given number of bits of integer and fraction digits. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code for the "Reciprocal Approximator", about halfway down this related page:
https://lauri.xn--vsandi-pxa.com/hdl/arithmetic/goldschmidt-divisor-implementation.html

It looks like a simple "count how many leading zero bits in the mantissa, put 16 - that many zeroes, then tack on '11'", at least in that implementation. So it's sort of like reflecting the binary representation around the "binary" point, with a little shifting.